# Passing arguments to multiple functions

Tags: function, design-patterns, methods, functional-programming

I have 2 general questions about function programming.

Consider the following 3 functions:

```
result = fun3(fun2(fun1(param1))); // param4

function fun1(param1) {
    // ...
    return param2;
}
function fun2(param2) {
    // ...
    return param3;
}
function fun3(param3) {
    // ...
    return param4;
}
```

Each function expects 1 parameter, does some computation and returns a variable.
In my case, every subsequent function relies on the output of the preceding function.

1. Is the solution in my example a common practice? Or are there better ways?
2. What if a function produces 2 outputs and 2 different functions need them?

Like in this example:

```
function fun1(param1) {
    // ...
    return param2, param3;
}
function fun2(param2) {
    // ...
    return param4;
}
function fun3(param3) {
    // ...
    return param5;
}
```

---

PS: Although this is a general programming questions, maybe it could be important to mention, that I use `PHP`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is that, yes, it's a very common technique in functional programming. It is, for example, the basis of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) which is also very common.

As regards the second question, many functional languages support the concept of a tuple or heterogeneous list - if you want to return multiple values you either explicitly create one or the runtime generates one for you on the fly. Sending return values into multiple subsequent functions would be done with the aid of a helper function which does the multiplexing. The question becomes how you handle the return values from those functions, presumably as a list I guess. It might depend on your use case.

In Python that might look like

```
def multiplex(functions, value):
    return [func(value) for func in functions]
```

To keep with your single-argument style the above might end up being curried in some fashion so that the list of functions to multiplex to are bound in a separate function application. Different languages achieve that in different ways, Python has a functools module which supports partial application of a function whereas Scala natively supports partially applying a function.